# sum rows indexed by consecutive days

Tags: python, pandas

I need to do some calculations based on the sum of measures made on consecutive days. So for example:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series
rng = pd.date_range('1/3/2000', periods=8)
rng = rng[:4].append(rng[5:])
ts = Series(randn(7).astype('int'), index=rng)
ts

Out[1]:
2000-01-03    0
2000-01-04    0
2000-01-05    0
2000-01-06   -1
2000-01-08    0
2000-01-09   -2
2000-01-10   -1
dtype: int64
```

How could I sum consecutive day values here, so I would get something like this?

```
Out[2]:
2000-01-03   -1
2000-01-04   -1
2000-01-05   -1
2000-01-06   -1
2000-01-08   -3
2000-01-09   -3
2000-01-10   -3
dtype: int64
```

**[Edit]**
[Similar problem solved in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197133/get-sum-of-consecutive-day-values)

Comment: Its hard to answer without seeing your input.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr the input is all there, except that I didn't include In[1]:

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems simpler now that I found the answer:

```
def ranks(series):
    """
    In an ORDERED series, this function identifies consecutive days
    giving each group an unique number identifier. Argument must be
    a pandas Series with datetime index.
    """
    td = series.index.to_series().diff()
    td[0] = timedelta64(1, 'D')
    res = []
    counter = 0
    for i in range(td.size):
        if td[i] > timedelta64(1, 'D'):
            counter += 1
        res.append(counter)
    return(Series(res, index=series.index))
```

From here, pandas [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html) takes care of it. ;-)

```
df = DataFrame({'val':ts, 'gr':ranks(ts)})
gr = DataFrame({'val':ts, 'gr':ranks(ts)}).groupby('gr')
df.merge(gr.sum(), left_on='gr', right_index=True, how='outer')
```

[image]