# Sum consecutive day values

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

In keeping with a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197133/get-sum-of-consecutive-day-values), imagine I have a data set:

```
Date       rain code
2009-04-01  0.0 0 
2009-04-02  0.0 0 
2009-04-03  0.0 0 
2009-04-04  0.7 1 
2009-04-05 54.2 1  
2009-04-06  0.0 0 
2009-04-07  5.0 1 
2009-04-08  9.0 0 
2009-04-09  0.0 0 
2009-04-10  0.0 0 
2009-04-11  0.0 0 
2009-04-12  5.3 1  
2009-04-13 10.1 1  
2009-04-14  6.0 1  
2009-04-15  8.7 1  
2009-04-16  0.0 0 
2009-04-17  0.0 0 
2009-04-18  0.0 0 
2009-04-19  2.0 0 
2009-04-20  3.0 0 
2009-04-21  0.0 0 
2009-04-22  0.0 0 
2009-04-23  0.0 0 
2009-04-24  0.0 0 
2009-04-25  4.3 1  
2009-04-26 42.2 1  
2009-04-27 45.6 1  
2009-04-28 12.6 1  
2009-04-29  6.2 1  
2009-04-30  1.0 1  

DT = structure(list(Date = structure(c(14335, 14336, 14337, 14338, 
14339, 14340, 14341, 14342, 14343, 14344, 14345, 14346, 14347, 
14348, 14349, 14350, 14351, 14352, 14353, 14354, 14355, 14356, 
14357, 14358, 14359, 14360, 14361, 14362, 14363, 14364), class = "Date"), 
    rain = c(0, 0, 0, 0.7, 54.2, 0, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 5.3, 10.1, 
    6, 8.7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.3, 42.2, 45.6, 12.6, 
    6.2, 1), code = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Date", "rain", "code"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to collapse the data set to get the sum of consecutive values of *rain* when *code* is 1. I need to have sum of them until the day after the event, inclusive. For example, I want to get sum of rain values from 2009-04-13 to 2009-04-06, and 2009-04-07 to 2009-04-08 separately. So I am trying to find way to define when the *code* is equal to 1 and the following day inclusive.  The final product ought to look like:

```
Date       rain code
2009-04-01  0.0 0 
2009-04-02  0.0 0 
2009-04-03  0.0 0  
2009-04-06  54.9 1  
2009-04-08  14.0 1 
2009-04-09  0.0 0 
2009-04-10  0.0 0 
2009-04-11  0.0 0 
2009-04-16 30.1 1 
2009-04-17  0.0 0 
2009-04-18  0.0 0 
2009-04-19  2.0 0 
2009-04-20  3.0 0 
2009-04-21  0.0 0 
2009-04-22  0.0 0 
2009-04-23  0.0 0 
2009-04-24  0.0 0  
2009-04-30  111.9 1  (if last entry of data frame)
```

Any help on the above problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is really a challenge to unambiguously express algorithms in natural language, isn't it?

Comment: Seems like you should also add +1 to the date on the last row of the result for consistency.

Comment: Fair thought, but if the world ends on 04-30, I can't assume 05-01. It should collapse to the last observable day. If I have to do that manually, so be it, because there is only one.

Comment: `diff` the `code`.  If it is 0, then you have successive days of rain/dry.  If `code == 1` and `diff(code) == 0` you have successive rainy days.  If you give reproducible data, I can try to play with it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

res = DT[, .(
  Date = Date[.N], 
  rain = sum(rain),
  code = code[1L]
), by=.(g = cumsum(shift(!code, fill=FALSE)))]

res[, g := NULL]

          Date  rain code
 1: 2009-04-01   0.0    0
 2: 2009-04-02   0.0    0
 3: 2009-04-03   0.0    0
 4: 2009-04-06  54.9    1
 5: 2009-04-08  14.0    1
 6: 2009-04-09   0.0    0
 7: 2009-04-10   0.0    0
 8: 2009-04-11   0.0    0
 9: 2009-04-16  30.1    1
10: 2009-04-17   0.0    0
11: 2009-04-18   0.0    0
12: 2009-04-19   2.0    0
13: 2009-04-20   3.0    0
14: 2009-04-21   0.0    0
15: 2009-04-22   0.0    0
16: 2009-04-23   0.0    0
17: 2009-04-24   0.0    0
18: 2009-04-30 111.9    1
```

*How it works:*

- `shift` is taking the value from the prior row
- When a logical value like `!code` is added up, TRUE/FALSE are treated as 1/0
- `.N` is the last row in the `by=` group

The general syntax is `DT[, j, by]` where `j` is computed using each `by` subset of data.

Comment: It is an integer indicator, @Regress, so I'm accessing the first element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use base R you can always use `diff` to calculate when the rain starts and stops.

```
start= which(diff(df$code)==1) +1
end = c(which(diff(df$code)==-1)+1, nrow(df))
l <- mapply(":", start, end)
```

Getting the data to collapse is just a matter of throwing out all other non stop day indices and replacing the last day with the following, which gets the cumulative rain amount on the day that it stops raining.

```
lapply(l, function(x) {
  df[x,][length(x),"rain"] <- sum(df[x,"rain"])
  df[x,][length(x),]
})

[[1]]
        Date rain code
6 2009-04-06 54.9    0
[[2]]
        Date rain code
8 2009-04-08   14    0
[[3]]
         Date rain code
16 2009-04-16 30.1    0
[[4]]
         Date  rain code
30 2009-04-30 111.9    1
```